# detecting arc and circle shapes in vector array with a range

Tags: c++, math, opengl-es, wolfram-mathematica

I have an array of 2d vertices and I want to detect if there are any arch or circle shapes in a array. Sometimes the values are not that precise and I need a small range. Here are the values. The 3rd verticle value value remains 0:

```
verticle:  -0.014848, -13.2684, 0 angle : 0.141274
verticle:  -0.0174556, -4.84519, 0 angle : 90
verticle:  0, 0, 0 angle : 90
verticle:  -9.53674e-07, 14.14, 0 angle : 40.7168
verticle:  -12.1101, 14.0709, 0 angle : 7.94458
verticle:  -12.0996, 10.6442, 0 angle : 0.294751
verticle:  -12.2305, 10.6484, 0 angle : 0.24309
verticle:  -12.325, 10.6384, 0 angle : 0.349426
verticle:  -12.4475, 10.6125, 0 angle : 0.392669
verticle:  -12.5638, 10.564, 0 angle : 0.404935
verticle:  -12.678, 10.508, 0 angle : 0.34605
verticle:  -12.7579, 10.4453, 0 angle : 0.391671
verticle:  -12.8315, 10.36, 0 angle : 0.390671
verticle:  -12.9051, 10.2747, 0 angle : 0.438795
verticle:  -12.9725, 10.1668, 0 angle : 0.455425
verticle:  -13.0377, 10.0514, 0 angle : 0.300014
verticle:  -13.0407, 9.94522, 0 angle : 0.388662
verticle:  -13.0738, 9.83064, 0 angle : 0.338041
verticle:  -13.0725, 9.70936, 0 angle : 0.254878
verticle:  -13.0412, 9.59645, 0 angle : 0.257171
verticle:  -13.0098, 9.48352, 0 angle : 0.259443
verticle:  -12.9785, 9.37061, 0 angle : 0.158259
verticle:  -12.9192, 9.27357, 0 angle : 0.0713262
verticle:  -12.8297, 9.18489, 0 angle : 0.14537
verticle:  -12.7724, 9.09539, 0 angle : 0.0484566
verticle:  -12.657, 9.03012, 0 angle : 0.0197823
verticle:  -12.5738, 8.96403, 0 angle : 0.125115
verticle:  -12.4667, 8.92887, 0 angle : 0.219397
verticle:  -12.3296, 8.90207, 0 angle : 0.185575
verticle:  -12.2288, 8.88951, 0 angle : 0.299361
verticle:  -12.1, 8.89282, 0 angle : 11.3066
verticle:  -12.1075, 5.64764, 0 angle : 0.158259
verticle:  -12.2062, 5.65268, 0 angle : 0.266879
verticle:  -12.3329, 5.64184, 0 angle : 0.312787
verticle:  -12.4554, 5.61594, 0 angle : 0.384104
verticle:  -12.5717, 5.56746, 0 angle : 0.322034
verticle:  -12.6557, 5.5198, 0 angle : 0.45024
verticle:  -12.7657, 5.44874, 0 angle : 0.416371
verticle:  -12.8415, 5.37097, 0 angle : 0.464781
verticle:  -12.913, 5.27815, 0 angle : 0.514343
verticle:  -12.9803, 5.17027, 0 angle : 0.436111
verticle:  -13.0176, 5.07075, 0 angle : 0.487788
verticle:  -13.0506, 4.95617, 0 angle : 0.439686
verticle:  -13.0515, 4.84242, 0 angle : 0.441462
verticle:  -13.0524, 4.72867, 0 angle : 0.470222
verticle:  -13.0511, 4.6074, 0 angle : 0.399585
verticle:  -13.0198, 4.49448, 0 angle : 0.402998
verticle:  -12.9885, 4.38156, 0 angle : 0.305828
verticle:  -12.9291, 4.28452, 0 angle : 0.237388
verticle:  -12.8396, 4.19585, 0 angle : 0.213062
verticle:  -12.7523, 4.1147, 0 angle : 0.188712
verticle:  -12.667, 4.04107, 0 angle : 0.0625573
verticle:  -12.5557, 3.99086, 0 angle : 0.0279765
verticle:  -12.4466, 3.94818, 0 angle : 0.0197823
verticle:  -12.3416, 3.92056, 0 angle : 0.158259
verticle:  -12.2107, 3.91634, 0 angle : 0.111906
verticle:  -12.1121, 3.9113, 0 angle : 17.8633
verticle:  -12.0988, 0.00704384, 0 angle : 15.2939
verticle:  -12.0895, -3.29836, 0 angle : 0.174713
verticle:  -12.2204, -3.29415, 0 angle : 0.100871
verticle:  -12.3471, -3.30499, 0 angle : 0.034264
verticle:  -12.4395, -3.32253, 0 angle : 0.0395647
verticle:  -12.5579, -3.36349, 0 angle : 0.139882
verticle:  -12.67, -3.42703, 0 angle : 0.170174
verticle:  -12.7499, -3.48974, 0 angle : 0.236563
verticle:  -12.8557, -3.57586, 0 angle : 0.266144
verticle:  -12.9293, -3.66115, 0 angle : 0.363156
verticle:  -12.9666, -3.76067, 0 angle : 0.357727
verticle:  -13.0339, -3.86855, 0 angle : 0.421973
verticle:  -13.067, -3.98313, 0 angle : 0.454565
verticle:  -13.0678, -4.09688, 0 angle : 0.452407
verticle:  -13.0687, -4.21063, 0 angle : 0.482545
verticle:  -13.0675, -4.3319, 0 angle : 0.487788
verticle:  -13.0361, -4.44482, 0 angle : 0.463094
verticle:  -12.9768, -4.54186, 0 angle : 0.421973
verticle:  -12.9496, -4.63972, 0 angle : 0.44279
verticle:  -12.8622, -4.72087, 0 angle : 0.402026
verticle:  -12.8071, -4.80285, 0 angle : 0.383084
verticle:  -12.7239, -4.86895, 0 angle : 0.399585
verticle:  -12.6105, -4.92668, 0 angle : 0.29074
verticle:  -12.5336, -4.97019, 0 angle : 0.30901
verticle:  -12.4266, -5.00535, 0 angle : 0.245493
verticle:  -12.3237, -5.02544, 0 angle : 0.214891
verticle:  -12.2229, -5.03801, 0 angle : 0.132704
verticle:  -12.0983, -5.01964, 0 angle : 11.875
verticle:  -12.0995, -8.28741, 0 angle : 0.300014
verticle:  -12.2304, -8.28319, 0 angle : 0.199792
verticle:  -12.327, -8.28568, 0 angle : 0.179137
verticle:  -12.4495, -8.31158, 0 angle : 0.121947
verticle:  -12.5679, -8.35253, 0 angle : 0.0395647
verticle:  -12.6799, -8.41607, 0 angle : 0.0279765
verticle:  -12.7598, -8.47878, 0 angle : 0.0442347
verticle:  -12.8657, -8.56491, 0 angle : 0.138476
verticle:  -12.9372, -8.65773, 0 angle : 0.199792
verticle:  -12.9765, -8.74972, 0 angle : 0.214891
verticle:  -13.0418, -8.86513, 0 angle : 0.275536
verticle:  -13.0749, -8.9797, 0 angle : 0.335718
verticle:  -13.0757, -9.09345, 0 angle : 0.359365
verticle:  -13.0745, -9.21473, 0 angle : 0.356083
verticle:  -13.0733, -9.33601, 0 angle : 0.39217
verticle:  -13.0419, -9.44893, 0 angle : 0.428872
verticle:  -12.9805, -9.55349, 0 angle : 0.402512
verticle:  -12.9211, -9.65052, 0 angle : 0.401538
verticle:  -12.8618, -9.74756, 0 angle : 0.417778
verticle:  -12.7744, -9.82871, 0 angle : 0.436559
verticle:  -12.659, -9.89397, 0 angle : 0.370094
verticle:  -12.5758, -9.96007, 0 angle : 0.338041
verticle:  -12.4687, -9.99522, 0 angle : 0.384613
verticle:  -12.3316, -10.022, 0 angle : 0.265408
verticle:  -12.2308, -10.0346, 0 angle : 0.261696
verticle:  -12.1041, -10.0237, 0 angle : 7.8231
verticle:  -12.1023, -13.1853, 0 angle : 42.4836
```

The only way I thought would fix this problem is a distance calculation combined with the angles that are bigger than a certain value. I know that is a bad solution. But I cannot think of any other way to calculate this.

This is how the angle calculation goes:

```
 inline float ofVec3f::angle( const ofVec3f& vec ) const {
ofVec3f n1 = this->normalized();
ofVec3f n2 = vec.normalized();
return (float)(acos( n1.dot(n2) )*RAD_TO_DEG);
 }
```

The distance between two points:

```
 inline float ofVec3f::distance( const ofVec3f& pnt) const {
float vx = x-pnt.x;
float vy = y-pnt.y;
float vz = z-pnt.z;
return (float)sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy + vz*vz);
  }
```

I've used the OpenFrameworks library to realize this:

```
float dist = buildings[x].polygon[z].distance(buildings[x].polygon[z+1]);
        float angle ;
        if ( z < buildings[x].polygon.size()-1){
            angle  =  buildings[x].polygon[z].angle(buildings[x].polygon[z+1]);
        }
         if ( ( dist >  0.100)&& ( dist <  0.150)) {
          //Is part of ellipse
       }
```

Here's a github of the library

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/math/ofVec3f.h

Here are two screen shots of the points and the line

[image: line]

[image: points]

Here's one vector array of verts  x,y x,y

```
-0.11878395,-106.14753 -0.13964462,-38.761494 0.0,0.0 -7.6293945E-6,113.11968 -96.88052,112.56717 -96.79668,85.153725 -97.843834,85.18742 -98.599945,85.107315 -99.58024,84.900116 -100.51039,84.51225 -101.42383,84.06417 -102.06295,83.562485 -102.65193,82.88013 -103.240906,82.197784 -103.77975,81.33476 -104.30187,80.41151 -104.325485,79.56175 -104.59001,78.64513 -104.5802,77.67491 -104.32949,76.77156 -104.07879,75.868195 -103.82809,74.96484 -103.35321,74.18856 -102.63742,73.47914 -102.17926,72.763084 -101.25601,72.24097 -100.59037,71.71221 -99.73398,71.43098 -98.63669,71.2166 -97.83043,71.11605 -96.8,71.14256 -96.859665,45.18112 -97.6492,45.22146 -98.66293,45.134716 -99.64322,44.92752 -100.57338,44.539658 -101.245926,44.158424 -102.12593,43.58989 -102.73163,42.96776 -103.303894,42.22518 -103.84273,41.36216 -104.14067,40.56599 -104.40518,39.649376 -104.412094,38.739384 -104.41901,37.8294 -104.409195,36.859184 -104.15849,35.955826 -103.90778,35.052475 -103.43291,34.27619 -102.71712,33.566765 -102.01806,32.917564 -101.33571,32.328587 -100.445885,31.92691 -99.57278,31.585457 -98.73309,31.364452 -97.68595,31.330748 -96.89641,31.290417 -96.790054,0.056350708 -96.71601,-26.386883 -97.76316,-26.353178 -98.77688,-26.439924 -99.51628,-26.580261 -100.46315,-26.907902 -101.35987,-27.416212 -101.99899,-27.917892 -102.84558,-28.606876 -103.434555,-29.289228 -103.732506,-30.0854 -104.27134,-30.948421 -104.53585,-31.86504 -104.542755,-32.77503 -104.54967,-33.685017 -104.53986,-34.655228 -104.28916,-35.558586 -103.81427,-36.33486 -103.59699,-37.117775 -102.897934,-37.766975 -102.456474,-38.422806 -101.79083,-38.95156 -100.8843,-39.41346 -100.2688,-39.761543 -99.41241,-40.04277 -98.58944,-40.203552 -97.78319,-40.30411 -96.78618,-40.157143 -96.79571,-66.299255 -97.84286,-66.26555 -98.615685,-66.285446 -99.59598,-66.49263 -100.54285,-66.820274 -101.439575,-67.32858 -102.07869,-67.83027 -102.92528,-68.51925 -103.497536,-69.261826 -103.8122,-69.99777 -104.33433,-70.92102 -104.59884,-71.83764 -104.60574,-72.74762 -104.59593,-73.717834 -104.58613,-74.68805 -104.33543,-75.5914 -103.84383,-76.42791 -103.36895,-77.204185 -102.89406,-77.98047 -102.195,-78.62967 -101.27175,-79.151794 -100.6061,-79.68055 -99.74972,-79.96178 -98.65242,-80.17615 -97.84617,-80.27671 -96.83245,-80.189964 -96.81836,-105.482315 -0.11878395,-106.14753
```

Other vector array

```
 0.0,46.766045 -5.8214893,46.69686 -5.820862,47.05351 -5.8475914,47.425262 -5.918213,47.749863 -6.0161915,48.08957 -6.1278477,48.43683 -6.283396,48.73693 -6.4526215,49.04459 -6.6794205,49.312645 -6.89254,49.573143 -7.1330166,49.848755 -7.4037094,50.069653 -7.6744003,50.290554 -7.988985,50.4643 -8.32011,50.57577 -8.621017,50.74196 -8.982357,50.79873 -9.330019,50.847942 -9.677681,50.897156 -10.011665,50.938812 -35.375645,50.81018 -64.38959,50.69822 -64.377785,49.620728 -64.35231,48.535683 -64.299484,47.435524 -64.20275,46.382523 -64.064995,45.30686 -63.91356,44.223648 -63.748447,43.132874 -63.525764,42.081707 -63.2894,41.022987 -63.025684,39.949158 -62.71807,38.922485 -62.38311,37.880703 -62.004246,36.886078 -61.611713,35.883904 -61.191822,34.86661 -60.758247,33.841774 -60.280785,32.86409 -59.759426,31.933561 -59.224392,30.995481 -58.67568,30.049845 -58.08307,29.151367 -57.476788,28.245333 -56.856827,27.331745 -56.162758,26.520025 -55.48522,25.646042 -54.777473,24.826767 -54.02583,24.05465 -53.304405,23.227821 -52.508865,22.502861 -51.69965,21.770344 -50.890438,21.037828 -50.051006,20.360025 -49.1979,19.674667 -48.314575,19.044018 -47.401035,18.468079 -46.504032,17.829878 -45.560276,17.30865 -44.602844,16.77987 -43.65909,16.258642 -42.671436,15.784572 -41.697464,15.318055 -40.693275,14.906249 -39.689087,14.494442 -38.654682,14.137346 -37.633957,13.787806 -36.58301,13.492973 -35.545746,13.205697 -34.478268,12.973131 -33.42446,12.748117 -32.340443,12.577815 -31.270102,12.415068 -30.18322,12.314583 -29.09634,12.2141 -28.006598,12.183435 -26.916859,12.152769 -25.840796,12.129659 -25.80352,9.967116 -25.811121,8.75754 -25.813,7.687599 -25.713875,0.20740414 -25.278425,0.25250435 -12.768033,0.054601192 -0.25477973,-0.073483296 0.0,0.0 0.0,46.766045
```

Comment: Because the distance is constant i thought  a simple distance calculation between the points would be the best solution. Its totally inaccurate. That's the only way I could think of :(

Comment: How would the vectors form an arc? Do you mean by putting them one after the other, one beginning where the last one ended, or when you plot them as points? Also, what is the "angle" column?

Comment: Sorry I mean vertices.

Comment: I can think of a few ways of fitting circular arcs into a set of points (for example, for each point fit a circle to its k-nearest neighbors and use a clustering algorithm to find those that fit best, or if the range of the points is limited, use a Hough transform) but I'd have to know a bit more about the origin of the data and how the points are distributed, e.g. if they form nice lines or if they are generated by some noisy random process..

Comment: It's building map information. I've added two examples of vector arrays with two floats in it. x,y x,y It's not allways nice lines.

Comment: if it is a continuous ordered path you might find the arc center of each 3 sucessive points, then look for clusters of centers that are near each other. whether this works or is better than a Hough transform depends on how noisy the data is.

Comment: A simple implementation of Hough works with the data, although the idea of testing neighboring data points for arc centers could work; in fact, that could work as an alternate method to feed a Hough accumulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Hough circle fit or RANSAC circle fit would probably work for you; in image processing we use these algorithms to find circles, arcs, ellipses, and other shapes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC

These algorithms work well with noisy data.

Gary Bradski's book Learning OpenCV has a section entitled "Hough Circle Transform" that runs a few pages. Although you might look at the OpenCV library itself, you'll probably find more straightforward descriptions of the Hough transform and RANSAC elsewhere.

**[EDIT]**

I wrote a quick Hough algorithm in C# and it worked well with your data. You could add random noise and it would still work. The core algorithm is about 100 lines of code with comments and spaces, and that's for a sloppy algorithm.

A portion of the output image from this algorithm is shown below with data points in white and Hough fit circles in red.

One standard algorithmic step I didn't implement is to filter data to eliminate all but the best circle fit when there are several reasonable circle fits with approximately the same center and approximately the same radius. That's why you see a double circle passing through the points.

Although a Hough algorithm might seem like overkill, what's nice is that it will work time and time again, it's reusable, it's easy to parameterize, and it will yield good results whether the data is clean or noisy.

[image: Hough circles on sample data]

NOTE: to simplify the implementation, I converted the float values for (x,y) to integers and normalized the values so that all (x,y) were positive. Something like this:

```
int x = (int)(100 * floatX + 1600);  //floatX = original X value in data
int y = (int)(100 * floatY + 3200);  //floatY = original Y value in data
```

Comment: I think this is to complex. It's just an array with  X and Y values. Is there a way that is a littlebit less complex and just calculates a possible follow-up verticle? As you see the data is not that noisy.

Comment: See my edit above. Your data looks just like the type of image for which we apply the Hough algorithm. It's possible to write a simple yet reusable version of the Hough algorithm; if my C# weren't a bit rusty it shouldn't have taken me more than about 10 - 20 minutes to write. (I write in C++, but C# is quicker for me for quick tests.) My concern with ad hoc algorithms to find circular arcs is that you would have to spend extra time developing methods to eliminate noise, delete outliers, etc. The parameters for Hough are  straightforward and correspond to circle parameters such as the radius.

Comment: Is there a possibility to share this code with me? Could you e-mail me this?

Comment: Sure, Martijn, I'd be happy to send you the code. It's late night C# code and not properly representative of the Hough technique, but I'll clean up the code and send it to you. Where should I send it? Expect an email from my gmail account.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Martijn. I just sent the sample code to your info address; you'll have to rebuild it with VS 2010.

Comment: Coming back to this question. I've solved my problem with : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-houghcircles. It's an fast and efficient algorithm that solved my problem.

Comment: Congrats! It's nice to have an open source solution. I hope I was able to help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

this is not a complete answer but an illustration of my above comment, finding arc centers of sucessive points..by trial and error it works best if you look at wider spread points (1,5,9) , (2,6,10) , etc.  (data here is a list of your x,y pairs)

```
arccenter[p_] := {xc, yc} /. 
   Solve[ { (p[[1]] - p[[2]] ).({xc, yc} - (p[[1]] + p[[2]])/2) == 
      0, (p[[2]] - p[[3]] ).({xc, yc} - (p[[2]] + p[[3]])/2) == 
      0 } , {xc, yc}][[1]]
pdata = Partition[data, 9, 1];
centers = arccenter[#[[{1, 5, 9}]]] & /@ pdata;
cc = Select[centers, Abs[#[[1]]] < 30 && Abs[#[[2]]] < 30 &];
Show[
     {Graphics[Point[#] & /@ data],
      Graphics[{Red, Point[#]} & /@ cc]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 0}, {-15, 15}}]
```

[image]

it should just take a little more effort to filter which centers are near each other.
(recall that they too are ordered..)

Comment: Could you clarify this ansfer for me a littlebit?